# Phone battery status on tizen web application

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-web-app

I would like to show Android phone (connected with tizen gear via 'Samsung Gear') battery status on my Gear S3.
My web application, can access watch battery status via `navigator.battery`. How can i access phone battery status?

Comment: By phone battery you meant the **Android/iOS phone** battery, connected with tizen gear via 'Samsung Gear' app, right?

Comment: exactly, Android phone battery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, There's no Tizen API/function to fetch Battery status of Companion mobile device. (Jun,2018)

So you can't show 'companion mobile battery status' using a function call or something like that.

If you really need this feature now:

As a workaround, You can develop an Android app and retrieve current battery level ([relevant Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#CurrentLevel)). Then send the data to Tizen gear using convenient communication channel (Bluetooth, HTTP).